# window.location (Plus Y offset) alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the old-school javascript:

```
window.location  = "#myAnchor";
```

to jump to a section of the page. However I would like to jump about 100 pixels higher than this anchor, to offset the persistent header navigation on the top of the page which covers this area.

I would consider jQuery since I am already using it on the site, or any other javascript-only solution. I can't place another anchor tag 100 pixels higher (plus that seems kind of hack-y). As well, window.location is a bit jarring, and I would rather scroll up there **smoothly**, somehow.

Can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could use **jQuery** it would be much more simple.
To scrool smothly, as you say, a sample code is this:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:500});
```

So, for you, i think this would solve:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(YOUR_ELEMENT).offset().top - 100) });
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: This works great! Except it was -100 (instead of +) since I wanted to be higher on the page. Much thanks!

Comment: Offsets start at 0 from the top of the document, so if you want to scroll to a point 100 pixels visibly above a certain point, you want to subtract (rather than add) 100 in the calculation.